# How to strip away empty paragraph tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an Rails 5 app.
In this app I am receiving html data from a WYSIWYG-form. In the content from the form I get a lot of empty

tags, how can I remove all these empty paragraph tags?

This is what I get:

```
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is really the only thing you want to scrub:

```
content.gsub('<p></p>', '')
```